# Network is unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, сеть

Всё хорошо работало, вернулся с работы, комп перестал отображать сайты "site is unreachable". Перезагрузил, мало ли, при включении выползает окошко LWUpchecker с текстом "failed to get version info from site open connection settings?". Открываю,там:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновления тоже не проходят. 
Команда:

```
sudo lshw -numeric -C network
```

Выдает вроде как данные о сет.карте.

Иногда на этом компе работаю с rails, но в тот день ничего не трогал точно.

Вывод конфига 
[image: Вывод config'a]

Comment: ifconfig посмотрите

Comment: Выполните команду dhclient `имя вашего сетевого интерфейса`. К примеру `dhclient eth0` или `wlan0`

Comment: @excellproj это если там не enp3s0 всякие...

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов я ж привёл просто для примера. Команда `ifconfig`  уже покажет, что там

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов приложил вывод конфига

Comment: @excellproj именно они

Comment: Примените `dhclient enp5s0`

Comment: Вроде по WiFi сеть должна быть, wlp4s0 даже адрес получил

Comment: @excellproj изменился значок сети wifi, на две стрелочки
network service discovery disable и далее описание какое-то о моем подключении к .local...

Comment: Сайты открывает?

Comment: @excellproj  нет

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить: интернет вы получаете по кабелю(Ethernet) или WiFi?

Comment: @excellproj посредством wifi